# Displaying Progressing Messages in windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window form containing a richtextbox. Upon button click event, as the process under this button click event takes time, i wanna display progressing messages in richtextbox. Like on every 500 records updates, i wanna display "500 records updated" and then "1000 records updated", and so on.

Right now, my messages display only when process is finished.  :(.

Comment: You might have meant to tag this `ado.net` instead of `asp.net`. This doesn't sound like an `asp.net` question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a thread to perform your processing and post a message back to the UI thread to update the progress bar.

Look into the [BackgroundWorkerThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8dcext2.aspx) class.

There are also quite a few questions on threading and its associated pitfalls here on Stack Overflow.